# How to change checked state of an input type radio in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, dom

I have a input type radio

```
const AnswerOptions = (props) => (
                   <>
                     <input
                        type="radio"
                        id="something"
                        name="something"
                        value={props.option}
                        onClick={e => save(e)}
                     ></input>
                     <label htmlFor="something">
                        <h1>{props.option}</h1>
                     </label>
                  </>
)

export default AnswerOptions
```

Then I am looping through an array and calling AnswerOptions for every item in the array;

```
import AnswerOptions from './AnswerOptions';

const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

const result = product[page].map((item) => {
  
return (
   <AnswerOptions 
           key={index}
           preset={preset}
           setSelected={setSelected}
           option={option}
           description={description}
    />
)

})
```

Then I am rendering the components.

```
<>
{result}
</>
```

I am doing this for multiple pages by changing the `page` variable and selecting the corresponding sub array.

The problem is the checkbox which is selected on the first page changes selection state of radio button of all the pages.So every page has same selected option.For example if I select second radio button from the top then all the pages are set on the second radio button as well. Selecting other option results the same. I need a way to control the radio check's initial and consequent states.

Setting defaultChecked and checked attributes did not work.

Comment: can you provide an example in jsfiddle or codepen? I can help you with real code

Comment: You're using `index` as `key` which is an anti-pattern precisely for this reason (though you're also not exposing `index` in the `map()`). You should rather use a unique identifier that applies to each checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@peter gave the correct answer in the comments. The issue was with key that I was providing to the component. Every `page` has an index of 0,1,2,3 and likewise. Which meant when I gave some data to index 1 of `page` 1, every other index 1 receives the same data. using uuid for keys solved this problem by providing unique identifiers for each `<AnswerOptions />` component.

We are supposed to use unique keys instead of an index anyways.